# Upload ICS (calandar) file to my server

Tags: server, calendar

I want to upload my ICS file to my server, well this is the easy part.

What I really want is to be able to share this *.ics file with 2-3 people so they can edit.

I have currently uploaded the file on the www/ (root)

```
mydomain.com.au/myfile.ics
```

of my server and added it to my Email/Cal client.

**Was all looking ok until I tried to save changes.**

Can someone please direct me to some documentation on how I do this properly.

The easy solution would be to upload to google, but I would rather learn how to manage the file myself.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you upload the file then it's read only for everyone. If you want to be able to save changes to it from your calendar client then you need to set it up so that it's available using Webdav. How you do that depends on your server.